# Should I answer my own question, or edit the best one?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, bounties

I've asked [a question some about customizing a UI element on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664208/twitter-esque-uitabbarcontroller). Since iOS 5 changes the internals of the element, I've been looking for a new answer to my question. I've added a bounty to my question, but then, I found my own answer (and posted the iOS5 portion of the answer as part of the the question until I figure out where to put it).

Should I edit the best answer to add my own additional code, or add my own? What happens to the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it depends upon how much editing is necessary; if it is just one or two new lines, then I'd say edit. If it requires more work, then I'd say give it a new answer and include a link to the existing 'best' answer, and reasoning why the changes are necessary.