# Should I revamp my own question or ask a new question?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I asked [a question regarding iPhone iframe widths at 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123960/how-to-get-iframe-width-100-in-iphone-portrait-view) and and in the end I found the solution myself. However now I had to deal with the exact same issue regarding iPads and in the process I actually got a better idea what was going own in the iPhone in the first place. Now the thing is I would like to post my findings, but I am not sure if I should edit my original question or ask a new question that handles the case in a general iOS form and answer that one.

Now the thing is that my first instinct was to simply edit the answer, but the new answer would be weird taking into consideration the question. Not to mention that I think it would be hard to find the answer based on the question, so I would like to completely revamp the original question as well (even the title of the question), but that seams a bit extreme.

I am also thinking of simply answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768621/size-of-content-in-iframe-in-ios-safari-iphone) with is much more like the final edited question I would like to make, but I feel like the answer would be almost a duplicate to my original question, not to mention even that question is only iPhone specific and not a general iOS Mobile Safari question.

By taking into account these questions [Should I ask a new question if my more detailed question is similar to an old unanswered question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134988/should-i-ask-a-new-question-if-my-more-detailed-question-is-similar-to-an-old-un) and [Should I answer my own question, or edit the best one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108795/should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-edit-the-best-one) I would say I should simply Q&A a new question, but then again, they are so similar. I really can't decide?

Comment: at Stack Exchange sites, *[“chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)* are not quite welcome

Answer (score 2):

Your question already has answers. So changing it to another question is not a good idea.

If the iPad question is seriously different than the iPhone one, you can post it as a new question, probably with a link to the previous.

Comment: Well the thing is that original answer I gave needs to be edited anyway, to basically the answer of the new question (before I lucked out, it worked, but the solution is actually incomplete). The problem is essentially the same, but manifests itself differently in iPhone and so although the solution is identical, the problem is not, unless you already know the answer. This is also one of the reasons why I am so stuck on this.

Comment: IMHO, you could create a new question, minimally edit your previous question, and add a link in your old question to the new one.

Comment: @outreal I am astutely aware how asking duplicate and junk questions counts against you i.e. towards getting a ban on asking questions and I am trying to avoid it. I already have couple of missteps and I do not want another one, but that thought did cross my mind.